# Importing a Spring AOP annotation into a separate project

Tags: java, spring, maven, aop, aspectj

I have two projects. One is a Spring Boot service, and the other is a library which is making use of Spring AOP. I have created a custom annotation to be executed whenever a method is annotated with this custom annotation. As I want this annotation to be used in lots of services, it lives inside the library. My code looks something like this:

Service:

```
@MyCustomAnnotation
  public void doSomething() {
    log.info("Do something is invoked!");
  }
```

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ApplicationConfig {
...
}
```

Library:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyCustomAnnotation {
...
}
```

```
@Aspect
public class ContinueTraceFromSpringKafkaEventAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(MyCustomAnnotation)")
    public void executeMyCustomAnnotation() { }

    @Before("executeMyCustomAnnotation()")
    public void beforeAnnotation(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        log.info("Before annotation");
    }

    @After("executeMyCustomAnnotation()")
    public void afterAnnotation(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        log.info("After annotation");
    }
}
```

The annotation would successfully execute when the code lived inside the service but, ever since extracting it to a library (and having the library on the classpath of the service via Maven dependency), it doesn't execute - I suspect the pointcut expression needs amending.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the package of the main Application class of the service? Which packages is it configured to scan? What is the package of the ContinueTraceFromSpringKafkaEventAspect class. If Spring Boot doesn't scan the class, then it's unknown from Spring, and is thus not applied.

Comment: @JBNizet Yep that solved it - completely forgot about the classpath scanning. Cheers!

Comment: @JBNizet, please write an answer the OP can accept in order to close this question.